# How to select all records from a table that do not exist in a union of two another tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, union

I want to return all records that do not exist in an union of two other tables but when i try to enclose the result of the union the workbench returns a syntax error. What i'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT TransactionID
from transactions 
where transactionid not in

(
(select distinct Transactionid
from transactionsdebits 
where   accountid like '81%')

union

(select distinct TransactionID
from transactionscredits
where accountid like '81%')
)
;
```

Comment: Consider having just the one table for transactions. Anyway, you have more parentheses than strictly necessary here, but I'm not sure that that's at the root of the problem

Comment: syntax wise query looks fine, error can be somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
    SELECT TransactionID
    from transactions 
    where transactionid not in ( select transactionid from
     (
       select distinct Transactionid
       from transactionsdebits 
       where   accountid like '81%'
       union
       select distinct TransactionID
       from transactionscredits
       where accountid like '81%'
     )
   A)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it also returns an 1064 syntax code error, can you please double check it?

Comment: It seems it lacks a left parenthesis

Comment: @AntónioManuelParaísoPinto, you can check now